# active admin view generation and skylight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, activeadmin

I am trying to understand some feedback I am getting from Skylight, I have an app with 2 seperated sections, one being a portal for users to manage applications and the other being an admin portal using active admin. When I look at the stats in skylight it reports that the user portal spends a regular amount of time on view rendering but when I look at the controllers handling the active admin code, a very high percentage of the time is spent in the view. I am wondering is this would be responsible for slow page loads and dyno issues on heroku, does anyone have some insight into these stats?

Active Admin index page:

[image: user portal]

User Portal page:
[image: user portal]

this same pattern repeats itself on all active admin pages, sometimes the veiw takes up 95% of the segment. Could this be caused because active admin is using ruby to generate the views everytime? could Active Admin be locking up the ruby processing and taking along time to process requests on heroku? any ideas why the stats show consistently high view segments? is this even a problem to begin with?

thanks for any feedback you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue, constantly running into workers being killed on Heroku due to excessive processing time for Active Admin views... however, this was when we were running on Unicorn server. Once we moved to Puma, that issue went away completely.

So, the first thing I would ask is what server you are running... if it is Unicorn, try moving to Puma (as of Jan 2015, it is the recommended server for Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/594 )

Here is the information on moving to Puma for Heroku (it does take a bit of work, but isn't too difficult)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

I hope this helps you!